# Group results in JSON Query

Tags: overpass-api

I'm querying two different keys (to just make one API call) and would like to group them in the returned results. Is this possible or are the results always a per node list?

Code:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
(
  node
  ["highway"="stop"]
  (around:5500,52.508088,13.465988);
);

(
   node
  ["highway"="traffic_signals"]
  (around:500,52.508088,13.465988);
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

The result should be:

```
  "elements": [
     [{stop},{stop},{stop}],
     [{traffic_signals},{traffic_signals},{traffic_signals}],
   ]
```

The current result is:

```
  "elements": [
     {stop},{stop},{stop},{traffic_signals},{traffic_signals},{traffic_signals},
   ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an artificial separtor element and output query queries via their own `out;` statement. Determine the array index for type=sep in the result and split the array in two parts accordingly .

```
[out:json];
node ["highway"="stop"](around:5500,52.508088,13.465988);
out;

make sep;
out geom;

node["highway"="traffic_signals"] (around:500,52.508088,13.465988);
out;
```

This question has also been discussed on the official Overpass API repo. See https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/issues/236 for further ideas to include additional tags per element.

Comment: works perfectly. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the reference. There appears to be no such way.

Comment: GitHub would have been the right place to find an answer here.